# Laravel + ajax pagination

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this code but it's working wrong. Animation not working and when I press button to go to next page then it makes two same sidebars with different content. How to make it to change nicely and don't make second the same sidebar ?

```
  <div id="ajaxContent">
    {!! $commentsLatest->render() !!}
    </div>

    <script>
    $('#ajaxContent').load('$commentsLatest');

    $('.pagination a').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if ( $(this).attr('href') != '#' ) {
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "fast");
            $('#ajaxContent').load($(this).attr('href'));
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: `$('#ajaxContent').load('$commentsLatest');`, is there any mistake ? i mean : `{!! $commentsLatest !!}`instead of `'$commentsLatest'` ?

Comment: $('#ajaxContent').load({{$commentsLatest}}); Now it's working but the problem is that the site url change to "?page=2" how to make sure that only content that changes is in panel ?